# How to make simple peer to peer chatting using android

Tags: java, android

I am developing chatting application using android. And my requirement is chatting. Now i am stuck that how i can achieve this for example through sockets, or through web services. I need to make my own server and then chatting between users. But i have no idea to do this. I also looking for complete example that how chatting will work but did not find any good example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use webservices.Before that you have to know about GCM.Learn about GCM.Then continue your chat application with hopefully :)

Comment: Yes can u explain me how it will work using web services. because i am confused

Comment: Create database.if sender send any msg then store it on the table.at the same time send the same msg to the receiver using GCM push notification :)